# How to detect library order for one pass linker?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, ld, unix-ar

Is there a tool that will analyze a large group of static archives, and order them for input to a one pass linker?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tsort-background.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for...

```
 lorder statica.a staticb.a | tsort
```

This will give you the list in the correct order.